# Hoard of bugs was/were squashed?

Tags: grammatical-number, collective-nouns

Is *hoard of bugs* to be treated as singular or plural?

1. > ...and what we mean by that is that a **hoard of bugs were** squashed relentlessly in this release
2. > ...and what we mean by that is that a **hoard of bugs was** squashed relentlessly in this release

Comment: *Hoard* or *horde*? Or -- easier to deal with -- *hordes of bugs*.

Comment: I would say the article "a" is a great giveaway for the plurality of the subject.

Comment: A valuable collection of lepidoptera or coleoptera might qualify as a hoard of bugs, but OP's sample sentence suggests the bugs in question are faulty software code, which presumably no one treasures, so *horde.*

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because  April Fools.